# Listview - Removing an item isn't reflected in View correctly

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problems with my ArrayAdapter Class. The problem is that the item is removed right in the refrigeratorItemList, but it is not reflected in the UI. In the view just the last item is removed, regardless which item was removed in the activity.

Activity.java(important part):

```
m_adapter.remove(m_adapter.getItem(id));
m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

RefrigeratorItemAdapter.java:

```
public class RefrigeratorItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RefrigeratorItem> {
private List<RefrigeratorItem> refrigeratorItemList;

public RefrigeratorItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<RefrigeratorItem> list) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
    this.refrigeratorItemList = list;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);

        RefrigeratorItem i = (RefrigeratorItem) getItem(position);

        System.out.println(i.toString());
        if (i != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            tt.setText(i.getProductname());
        }
    }
    return v;

}

public void remove(RefrigeratorItem object) {
    super.remove(object);
    this.refrigeratorItemList.remove(object);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(refrigeratorItemList.toArray()));
}

 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the Views in a wrong way. Try it like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    }

    RefrigeratorItem i = (RefrigeratorItem) getItem(position);

    System.out.println(i.toString());
    if (i != null) {
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tt.setText(i.getProductname());
    }
    return v;
}
```

When v is not null, it means that the View already has been shown, and you can now reuse it for your new item. You do need to, however, update the contents of the view.

For example, if you have 5 list items on screen:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5
```

Now you scroll, resulting in this:

```
2  
3  
4  
5  
6
```

The view that contained '1' is now used to show '6'. In your code however, you do not update te content from the textview from 1 to 6.